# Roommate not on the lease wants to move out without giving 30 day notice

Tags: residential-lease, rent, notice

My friend, call him F1, rents an apartment month to month and is required to give 30 days notice when he wants to move out. He rents to another friend of ours who is not on their lease, call him F2.

F2 told F1 that he was looking at apartments closer to his job on the 7th of January. It's now the 11th of January and F2 hasn't told him wether or not he's moving out, but it's almost guaranteed that he does.

F1 asked him for half of Febuarys rent, because F1 legally couldn't move out until March now but F2 isn't agreeing to that.

Since F2 isn't on a lease, and F1 didn't have him sign anything when he moved in, can he legally ask for half of Febuary. I personally think he should ask for all of Febuary but he's trying to be nice since they have been friends for a long time.

Location is New York USA

Comment: If nothing was signed between the two friends, then it becomes a question of what's the locales laws on sub-letting and default notice periods?  If there aren't any default notice periods for sub-lets, F2 can walk away the next day - the 30 day period on the lease doesn't bind them as they aren't on it, and there is nothing statutory, so....

Comment: This needs the country and specific location tags, so local law can be drawn on.

Comment: Does F1's lease allow him to have F2 living there for an extended period in the first place? If not this may diminish F1's claim to begin with.

Comment: Not worth posting as an answer - there's unlikely to be a law against asking, but without a contract (or local default assumptions) F1 has nothing to enforce.

Comment: So F2 is refusing to pay for any days in February? He should at least pay a prorated amount until he moves out.

Comment: Added location (New York). I lived with F1 originally, then when I moved out our friend F2 moved in. The lease doesn't say anything specific about renting out the 2nd room, but the landlord was informed and was okay with it.

Comment: @mkennedy reading it, I understand it that F1 wants F2 to commit to at least half of February rent right now, because a 30 day period from any point right now means F2 is committed to half of February.  F2 isnt refusing to pay rent in February, tehy are refusing to commit to 30 days notice - if F2 left on the 30th of January, F1 wants their rent paid up until some point in mid-February as that is what they are insisting they are obliged to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legal situation is unclear. I assume that only F1 has a written lease with the property owner for a tenancy at will, and that F1's arrangement with F2 is informal (if there is a written contract, that would govern the situation). In lieu of specific statutes governing the situation, F2 would have no notice obligation to F1 unless there is an agreement that F2 must provide 30 days notice. There are laws like [NY Real Prop L § 228](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2017/rpp/article-7/228/) which impose a 30 day notice requirement, but this notice is "given  in  behalf  of  the  landlord,  to  the  tenant", i.e. it's a requirement imposed on the landlord, not the tenant. [§232-a](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2017/rpp/article-7/232-a/) likewise imposes restrictions  regarding notice to terminate tenancy on landlords, but not on tenants.
The law does not compel a tenant (F1) to give notice to a landlord (F2) some minimum number of days in advance.